# Is there any way to store different datatypes in one single variable during runtime

Tags: c++, c

I am new to programming language , is there any way to store different datatypes in one single variable during runtime.
EX:

```
class a
{
    void b(anydatatype var)
    int ab;
}
void a::b(anydatatype var)
{
    ab = var;
    //how can i make this possible to assign any data type to that int?
}
```

It would be of great help if i get the solution without using templates

Comment: You can use unions (but you'll need to keep track of what type you're storing)

Comment: Unions or void*, but depends strongly on what you need to do.

Comment: Why without templates?  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: C++ is a strongly typed language, it does not allow this. However, you may try unions or Boost::any.

Comment: At this point, it would really help if you explained what you are actually trying to do, so we can give you the right solution. Why not templates - that's what they are for, after all?

Comment: Thank you for your response,To be specific let us consider ,i have an enum of type 'a' which is going to be assigned of enum type 'a' and also say of enum type 'b' and 'c' . so my doubt is how can i assign different enum types like b and c to enum type 'a' which is already defined in a particular  class that cant be changed.

Answer (score 7):

There is no built-in C++ solution for this use case.  However there are libraries built on top of C / C++ which provide this type of functionality.

- C++ Boost Variant: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html
- C libcello: http://libcello.org/

Comment: would libcello be a viable solution for `C`?

Comment: @TaylorFlores i'm unfamiliar with libcello.  I took a quick glance though and it appears that it would

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways you could do this. A [union](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/) lets you store multiple different types of data in the same memory location, but the space used will be the space required by the largest data type, and you'll have to know the type when you add it or remove it:

```
// This will take 8 bytes because a long is int64_t is 8 bytes
union MyUnion {
  int32_t regular_int;
  int64_t big_int;
}

MyUnion var;
// Stores an int32_t in var
var.regular_int = 100;
// replaces it wiht an int64_t
var.big_int = 100;
```

[Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/variant.html) provides a nice object oriented wrapper around the idea of a variant and allows you to include non-POD types.

You can also create your own set of classes that allows you to do this and provide functionality that is useful for your application. For example, if you need to be able to write all value types to stdout the following might be useful:

```
class MyVariant {
 public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
}

template<class T> MyVariantType public MyVariant {
 private:
    private T data_;

 public:
    MyVariantType(T data) {
        data_ = data;
    }

    virtual void print() {
        cout << data_;
    }
}

MyVariant* var = new MyVariantType<int>(100);
var->print();
var = new MyVariantType<string>("hello world");
var->print();
```

Finally, if you're truly desperate, you can use void* pointers and do casting, but this isn't recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Well no such thing exist exactly for this purpose in C++ but you can use `union`. It can serve the purpose. You can also try some third party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use void* to hold values of different types but you will lose all the benefits of an strongly type language. Cello (http://libcello.org/) uses this approach to implement a version of duck typing in C.

If you know all the different types that the variable could hold, then an union seems like a proper tool for the job.